# Representation of current time into double/long in java

Tags: java

How can i convert the current time and past 24 hours time into the long or double in java?

Comment: What do you need the long or double for?

Comment: You can get current time via System.currentTimeMillis(). Then you can manipulate it by adding 1 for each millisecond you want to add (if you want to add a day, just use System.currentTimeMillis + (24*60*60*1000))

Comment: Please, try to be at least a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//your current time in long (milliseconds)
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());//time, 24 hours earleir in long (milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java the System.currentTimeMillis() is represented as a `long` already.

To convert to a `double` as fraction of the current day, you can find the start of the current day, subtract this from the current time and divide by the number of milli-seconds in a day.